# Normalize SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, normalization

I'm creating a database for a project and I'm a little confused about how normalization applies to my schema. Everytime a loan is aproved for a customer, they have 2 options a check or an EFT, so I want to know wheter the loan was a check or EFT.

This are my 3 tables:

**Loans**

```
id_loan (PK)
product
amount 
status
```

**Checks**

```
id_check (PK)
id_customer
amount
```

**EFT**

```
id_eft (PK)
id_customer
amount
```

Then I created a 4th table to establish a relationship between loans and money disposal.

**Disposal**

```
id_payment (PK)
id_loan (FK loans)
id_disposal (FK checks or EFT)
disposal_type
```

In this table I store whether the loan is related to a check or an EFT, disposal_type field is a varchar with two possible values "check" or "EFT". id_disposal field acts as a foreign key for two tables.

The problem is that I think my database isn't normalized with this structure, am I right? What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you always make a single payment, either with one check or with one EFT, to the person who's getting a loan?

Comment: No, some loans may require more than one check or EFT, or even both

Comment: "id_disposal (FK checks or EFT)" -- this is a design problem: you can't define such a FK because id_eft and id_customer are different logical types, even if they happen to be of the same SQL data type. You need a further supertype table. Google for SQL subclassing. Your problem is not related to normalization, however.

Comment: Thanks onedaywhen actually that was the way I solved this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like the attached. Note that the customer_loans table is kind of extraneous and overkill, but if there's any columns that relate to the customer and the loan, and not the customer's loan payments, that's where it would go.

[image: Loans Schema]

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply Wil, in fact there were some fields I wasn't considering but now I know how to add them using your schema.

Comment: The real problem is that checks and EFTs each have identity, and a payment application needs to store that with some degree of integrity.  Checks have check numbers; EFTs have something else.

Comment: Catcall - the check numbers and EFT numbers are *external* identifiers, and can be treated as such. They don't uniquely identify the payment...for example, two banks can issue the same check number. The *payment*, however, can be uniquely identified through the customer, amount, method of payment, etc. There are many ways to skin a cat, but the schema Jorge needs can be created with smashing 3NF to bits.

Answer (score 2):

In the object world, you'd use inheritance for this. There would be a base type Disposal which CheckDisposal and EftDisposal would derive from. Modern O/RMs support several techniques for mapping this to a relational structure.

TablePerHierarchy puts all of the records into a single table with a discriminator column to identify what type a specific record holds and maps to. The advantage is that it requires fewer joins to get a record. Disadvantage is that it requires app logic to enforce data integrity.

TablePerType maps records into different tables with a fk relationship back to the base table. Of course this requires more joins (especially for deep or wide hierarchies) but data integrity can be enforced in the DB.

Comment: what about using linq to entities?

Comment: Entity Framework supports both of these strategies. Are you using 4.1 Code first? (I recommend that)